# remove and addClass only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm developing a menu that has two modes, when the user clicks on one of them the class of a list item changes, I can get it to work at the first mode change but when I try to change back  it does not work.

this is my code

```
$('#menu ul.mode li.edit').click(function() {
    $('#menu').css('background-image', 'url(images/edit-menu/fundo.png)');
    });
    $('#menu ul.icons li.ummix').removeClass('ummix').addClass('um');


$('#menu ul.mode li.mix').click(function() {
    $('#menu').css('background-image', 'url(images/edit-menu/fundo-mix.gif)');
    $('li.um').removeClass('um').addClass('ummix');

});
```

the part that doesn't work is

```
$('#menu ul.icons li.ummix').removeClass('ummix').addClass('um');
```

My HTML is like this

```
<div id="menu">
<ul class="mode">
    <li class="edit"><a href="#edit"><img src="images/edit-menu/selected/edit.gif" /></a></li>
    <li class="mix"><a href="#mix"><img src="images/edit-menu/icons/mix.png" /></a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="icons"> 
    <li class="um"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding and removing opposite classes becomes unwieldy.

*Assuming* that `unmix` and `um` are opposites of one another, I would encourage you to use just one class. Then check for its existence or nonexistence. At that point you could simply use something like `toggleClass()`.

Comment: Caught me mid-edit. Nonetheless, I suppose this is more of a *teach to fish* answer.

Answer (score 0):

After you remove the `ummix` class, the selector no longer applies to those elements. Try adding the `um` class before removing the `ummix` one.

Comment: Removing the class doesn't change which elements are selected, unless i'm mis-understanding what you are saying.

Comment: Assuming jQuery optimises the selector to use `getElementsByClassName`, the object contains a NodeList. Not a StaticNodeList. Meaning it updates when the DOM changes. Since the class is being removed, it is no longer a part of the NodeList and therefore won't be affected by the `addClass` call.